# String to UCS-2

Tags: go

I want to translate in `Go` my `python` program to convert an `unicode` string to a `UCS-2` `HEX` string.

In python, it's quite simple:

```
u"Bien joué".encode('utf-16-be').encode('hex')
-> 004200690065006e0020006a006f007500e9
```

I am a beginner in `Go` and the simplest way I found is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "Bien joué" 
    fmt.Printf("str: %s\n", str)

    ucs2HexArray := []rune(str)
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%U", ucs2HexArray)
    a := strings.Replace(s, "U+", "", -1)
    b := strings.Replace(a, "[", "", -1)
    c := strings.Replace(b, "]", "", -1)
    d := strings.Replace(c, " ", "", -1)
    fmt.Printf("->: %s", d)
}

str: Bien joué
->: 004200690065006E0020006A006F007500E9
Program exited.
```

I really think it's clearly not efficient. How can-I improve it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need the output limited to UCS-2? Your Python example is for UTF-16BE, which isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this conversion a function then you can easily improve the conversion algorithm in the future. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode/utf16"
)

func hexUTF16FromString(s string) string {
    hex := fmt.Sprintf("%04x", utf16.Encode([]rune(s)))
    return strings.Replace(hex[1:len(hex)-1], " ", "", -1)
}

func main() {
    str := "Bien joué"
    fmt.Println(str)
    hex := hexUTF16FromString(str)
    fmt.Println(hex)
}
```

Output:

```
Bien joué
004200690065006e0020006a006f007500e9
```

NOTE:

You say "convert an unicode string to a UCS-2 string" but your Python example uses UTF-16:

```
u"Bien joué".encode('utf-16-be').encode('hex')
```

> [The Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/)
>
> [UTF-16 FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#UTF16)
>
> [Q: What is the difference between UCS-2 and UTF-16?](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-11)
>
> A: UCS-2 is obsolete terminology which refers to a Unicode
>   implementation up to Unicode 1.1, before surrogate code points and
>   UTF-16 were added to Version 2.0 of the standard. This term should now
>   be avoided.
>
> UCS-2 does not describe a data format distinct from UTF-16, because
>   both use exactly the same 16-bit code unit representations. However,
>   UCS-2 does not interpret surrogate code points, and thus cannot be
>   used to conformantly represent supplementary characters.
>
> Sometimes in the past an implementation has been labeled "UCS-2" to
>   indicate that it does not support supplementary characters and doesn't
>   interpret pairs of surrogate code points as characters. Such an
>   implementation would not handle processing of character properties,
>   code point boundaries, collation, etc. for supplementary characters.

Answer (score 3):

For anything other than trivially short input (and possibly even then), I'd use the [`golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode) package to convert to UTF-16 (as @peterSo and @JimB point out, slightly different from obsolete UCS-2).

The advantage (over `unicode/utf16`) of using this (and the `golang.org/x/text/transform` package) is that you get BOM support, big or little endian, and that you can encode/decode short strings or bytes, but you can also apply this as a filter to an `io.Reader` or to an `io.Writer` to transform your data as you process it instead of all up front (i.e. for a large stream of data you don't need to have it all in memory at once).

E.g.:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
)

const input = "Bien joué"

func main() {
    // Get a `transform.Transformer` for encoding.
    e := unicode.UTF16(unicode.BigEndian, unicode.IgnoreBOM)
    t := e.NewEncoder()
    // For decoding, allows a Byte Order Mark at the start to
    // switch to corresponding Unicode decoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE, or UTF-16LE)
    // otherwise we use `e` (UTF-16BE without BOM):
    t2 := unicode.BOMOverride(e.NewDecoder())
    _ = t2 // we don't show/use this

    // If you have a string:
    str := input
    outstr, n, err := transform.String(t, str)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("string:   n=%d, bytes=%02x\n", n, []byte(outstr))

    // If you have a []byte:
    b := []byte(input)
    outbytes, n, err := transform.Bytes(t, b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("bytes:    n=%d, bytes=%02x\n", n, outbytes)

    // If you have an io.Reader for the input:
    ir := strings.NewReader(input)
    r := transform.NewReader(ir, t)
    // Now just read from r as you normal would and the encoding will
    // happen as you read, good for large sources to avoid pre-encoding
    // everything. Here we'll just read it all in one go though which negates
    // that benefit (normally avoid ioutil.ReadAll).
    outbytes, err = ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("reader: len=%d, bytes=%02x\n", len(outbytes), outbytes)

    // If you have an io.Writer for the output:
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    w := transform.NewWriter(&buf, t)
    _, err = fmt.Fprint(w, input) // or io.Copy from an io.Reader, or whatever
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("writer: len=%d, bytes=%02x\n", buf.Len(), buf.Bytes())
}

// Whichever of these you need you could of
// course put in a single simple function. E.g.:

// NewUTF16BEWriter returns a new writer that wraps w
// by transforming the bytes written into UTF-16-BE.
func NewUTF16BEWriter(w io.Writer) io.Writer {
    e := unicode.UTF16(unicode.BigEndian, unicode.IgnoreBOM)
    return transform.NewWriter(w, e.NewEncoder())
}

// ToUTFBE converts UTF8 `b` into UTF-16-BE.
func ToUTF16BE(b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    e := unicode.UTF16(unicode.BigEndian, unicode.IgnoreBOM)
    out, _, err := transform.Bytes(e.NewEncoder(), b)
    return out, err
}
```

Gives:

```
string:   n=10, bytes=004200690065006e0020006a006f007500e9
bytes:    n=10, bytes=004200690065006e0020006a006f007500e9
reader: len=18, bytes=004200690065006e0020006a006f007500e9
writer: len=18, bytes=004200690065006e0020006a006f007500e9
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard library has the built-in `utf16.Encode()` (https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/#Encode) function for this purpose.